# two separate strategies working independently within one strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am sharing my sample code. the problem is as follows: it does each operation sequentially. as seen in the picture, the 2nd strategy opens shorts, returns to long with the 1st strategy, returns to shorts again with the 1st strategy. whereas I want each strategy to work independently.

```
//@version=5
strategy("2 in 1 sample", overlay=true, close_entries_rule="ANY")


stopPer = input.float(2.0, title='Stop Loss %'  ) / 100
takePer = input.float(4.0, title='Take Profit %' ) / 100

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopPer)
shortTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takePer)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePer)

//strategy 1
s1eg1 = ta.ema(close, 5)
s1eg2 = ta.ema(close, 32)

long1 = ta.crossover(s1eg1, s1eg2)
short1 = ta.crossunder(s1eg1, s1eg2)

if long1
    strategy.entry("LONG1", strategy.long)

if short1
    strategy.entry("SHORT1", strategy.short)



if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Long1", from_entry="LONG1", stop=longStop, limit=longTake)
if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short1", from_entry="SHORT1", stop=shortStop, limit=shortTake)



//strategy 2
s2eg1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
s2eg2 = ta.ema(close, 20)

long2 = ta.crossover(s2eg1, s2eg2)
short2 = ta.crossunder(s2eg1, s2eg2)

if long2
    strategy.entry("LONG2", strategy.long)

if short2
    strategy.entry("SHORT2", strategy.short)



if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Long2", from_entry="LONG2", stop=longStop, limit=longTake)
if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short2", from_entry="SHORT2", stop=shortStop, limit=shortTake)
```

[image]

it does each operation sequentially. as seen in the picture, the 2nd strategy opens shorts, returns to long with the 1st strategy, returns to shorts again with the 1st strategy. whereas I want each strategy to work independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hedging is not supported on Tradingview. So, you cannot have one long and short positions open at the same time. The opposite direction entry will close the other one.

If you really want, you can do it in an indicator. In that case, you need to simulate all the functionalities and statistics of a strategy which is not an easy job.